# Load array of functions inside a Foreach / add entry to hostfile based on a environment file

Tags: powershell

This is probably not a good title, but I don't know how to explain it.

I'm trying to add host entry to the host file based on a environment file, I've imported "**carbon**" framework into my environment. The output seems to be correct but It's not "running". When I manually try to type in one of the entry everything works perfect.

```
Set-HostsEntry -IPAddress 127.0.0.1 -HostName 'portal.sp2013dev.no' -Description 'Portal'
```

Problem is that it only write the line in console, but It does not execute!

Environment.ps1

```
`####### INSIDE HOSTFILE I GOT A ARRAY THAT I WANT TO PASTE INTO THE OTHER FILE 
 #HostFile
    $hostFileEntry = @("Set-HostsEntry -IPAddress 127.0.0.1 -HostName 'portal.sp2013dev.no' -Description 'Portal'" , 
    "Set-HostsEntry -IPAddress 127.0.0.1 -HostName 'mysite.sp2013dev.no' -Description 'Mysite'" , 
    "Set-HostsEntry -IPAddress 127.0.0.1 -HostName 'tt.dev.no' -Description 'profile'")
```

Hostfile.ps1

```
###############################################################################
# ADD / REMOVE HOST ENTRYS TO HOST FILE
###############################################################################

Try
{
 . .\Environment.ps1
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
"Problems accessing environment file, check the file location"
"Terminating script"
Break
}

#Reset Host file 
#Reset-HostsFile

#Adding host entry's to host file
Foreach ($entry in $hostFileEntry)
{
   $entry
}
```

Comment: Is this just outputting strings? Should be able to fix this with `& $entry` or possibly `Invoke-Expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell PowerShell that the string contained in `$entry` needs to be executed. The simple answer should be to use [Invoke-Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx) which runs commands or expressions on the local computer.

```powershell
Foreach ($entry in $hostFileEntry)
{
   Invoke-Expression $entry
}
```

Before you were just sending the string to standard output* (* FYI output is odd from that `ForEach($b in $a)` construct).

Comment: Ty, I just made a multriple array that send all aruments in. But I'll use this later !